# Sqlalchemy: Purpose of .all()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What is the use of .all(). When the following function

```
def showRestaurants():
restaurants = session.query(Restaurant)
return render_template('restaurant.html',restaurants=restaurants)
```

Returns the same result as this function

```
def showRestaurants():
restaurants = session.query(Restaurant).all()
return render_template('restaurant.html',restaurants=restaurants)
```

For this restaurant.html file

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> Restaurants </h1>

{% for x in restaurants %}
</br>

{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First example returns `Query` object and you can apply additional methods on it, such as `all()` - it will return results represented by that `Query` as a list.

`Query` object works on each row before give it, while the second works on all rows, before starting to give them.

Comment: Why can I iterate over the query object in the html file. Since both are of different types

Comment: i added some explanation

Comment: you can iterate over the object becaus it has __iter__ method

Answer (score 0):

it just executes your query and returns a list with results, see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all

alternatively you can execute the query manually:

```
session.execute(Restaurant.select())
```